# DeltaTime not updating properly?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having trouble with my deltaTIme basically what I'm trying to do is add 1 every second to a variable.

```
private int num=0
private float deltaTime=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

public void render(){
    deltaTime=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();// updating

    num += 1*deltaTime;
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

and the output is this

```
    0
    0.016612083 //it does not add 1 to num every second
    0
    0.016679354
    0
    0.016680228
    0
    0.016672073
    0
```

Comment: You have to increment. num += 1*deltaTime; num++; But I am not sure what you are trying to achieve doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using num++ is wrong because it would just add 1 to num every time you call the render-function.
I cant see whats wrong in your code, so probably the delta time is not updated properly.

Comment: I know before it was working, then I deleted a package and some classes and now it doesn't. deltaTime is updated properly it's in the render() method.

Comment: Where do you call the render function? And what does your program do in general?

Comment: right now it doesn't do anything, I'm just testing some stuff. I'm implementing ApplicationListener which includes render method.

Comment: I always computed it myself using System.nanoTime so you have more control

Comment: If the time was correct how could num decrease to zero again?

Comment: these are the values of deltaTime when called 0.016955134,
0.016349116, 
0.016663337,
0.016701486, I'm not sure though if it's correct

Comment: The values look okay but how does num decrease if the deltaTime value is positive? The fault is probably not in the code you showed us..

Comment: Looks like you re-initialize num every time you call the render function

Comment: The problem is, that num is an `int` and `int` cuts off fraction digits. So the operation 0 + 0.016 results in 0.

Answer (score 2):

LibGDX's `deltaTime` is a `float` and the amount of time (in seconds) that passed since the last frame.

You want to have a `float` variable to keep track of the time, because `int` won't work here.

```
float timePassed = 0f;

public void render() {
    timePassed += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if (timePassed >= 1f) {
        // one second has passed and you can do something
    }
}
```

Comment: But before it worked, basically what I'm doing is adding 1 every second I don't understand why now isn't working.

Comment: @StormAsdg i am pretty sure it never worked like this, as you are not adding 1 every secont, but you are adding delta every renderloop, which is a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your num is an `int`. Therefore the fractiondigits are cut, resulting in num being zero all the time.
Solution: Make num a `float`, it will increment by delta every render loop.

> basically what I'm doing is adding 1 every second I don't understand why now isn't working

You are not, you are adding delta every render loop. To do what you want to do, keep a `float elapsedTime` and increment `num` only, if `elapsedTime` is bigger then 1. Then decrease `elapsedTime` by 1.

```
private int num;
private float elapsedTime;

public void render() {
    elapsedTime+=Gdx.graphics.getDelta();
    if (elapsedTime >= 1f) {
        num++;
        elapsedTime-=1f;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.  Make `num` into a float and cast it to an int when you need just the whole seconds.

```
float num;

public void render(){

    //...

    num += deltaTime;

    if ((int)num >= SOME_CRITERION)
        doSomething();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer.

```
    Task task = new Task() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            num++;
        }
    };
    //Here we start the timer 
    timer = new com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer();
    //We execute 'task' every second with 0 delay
    timer.scheduleTask(task, 0, 1);
```

You just have to call this once, so you shouldn't call it in the render() function.

Comment: it will be asynchronous - quite unsafe

Comment: @m.antkowicz The libgdx Timer does execute synchronously on the same thread as the render method.